# Several programs have suddenly stopped launching properly. Why might this be, and how could I fix it?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, troubleshooting, application-launch

(I think this is the right Stack Exchange for troubleshooting questions? If not, please do point me to the right site and I'll repost this there!)

For the last couple of weeks, I've been having problems with my desktop.

The first issue to emerge was with file explorer. One day, it suddenly started opening itself about once in every two times I went into and out of full screen. It seemed to be random when it would do it; or at least, I didn't manage to discern any pattern. A couple of days later, this mysteriously stopped happening, but I found I am now unable to open file explorer at all using the pinned icon on the taskbar which is included by default in Windows. When I click on it, nothing happens. At first, I was able to right click on the icon in the taskbar and click a pinned/recent folder to open file explorer, but that stopped working about a day later. Now I can open the right click menu, but clicking on any folders listed in the taskbar right-click menu does nothing. It doesn't even close the right-click menu. I am, however, able to launch file explorer through the start menu, or even through a shortcut to explorer.exe pinned onto my taskbar; just not from the actual pinned program with the appropriate right click menu, etc. File explorer also now has a habit of going non-responsive when I right click on files.

I have also noticed other programs have not been loading properly. In particular, Skype decided to update itself, and got stuck part way through the update. After that, whenever I tried to load it, it would simply get stuck on a loading screen. I uninstalled Skype (which took way longer than it should have) and tried to reinstall it, but the installer just freezes on "preparing to install".

Most recently, today I've discovered that Steam also isn't loading. It gets stuck at "Connecting Steam account" (the little black box that normally shows up for a few seconds just before Steam opens; or stays up for half a minute and then is replaced by an error box if you don't have internet). I don't use Steam that much, so this could well have been the case for the last while and I just didn't notice.

I'm running a virus scan now (using Sophos), but it seems to have got stuck at 2% completed. The file it's scanning keeps changing, but I've left it for a while and the progress meter hasn't gone up at all. This could just be me being impatient, of course. Previously, when the problems started, I ran another scan using Avast, which also seemed to get similarly stuck for quite a while. In fact, I left it running overnight, and when I came back in the morning it seemed to have completed the scan and didn't report any issues.

I'd do a system restore, but I've checked and I only appear to have one from after the problems appeared. (This in itself confuses me, I have a good 100GB or so left on my hard drive, so surely it shouldn't have been deleting stuff to save space yet?) I've tried using the system file checker utility (sfc/scannow); it identified and fixed some things it thought were issues, but didn't stop the problems. I also reinstalled my videocard driver; it was shortly after that that file explorer went from opening itself when I didn't want it to, to not opening when I told it to; and then that the other problems started appearing. Other than that, I haven't yet tried any fixes, mostly because I haven't got a clue what's going on.

My computer is a windows 10 (formerly 7) desktop, with a 1TB harddrive, 16GB RAM, Nvidia graphics card. It's a self-built computer, which I've had for about 7-8 years, upgrading the occasional part. I don't recall making any changes to my system in the time before problems started happening, other than installing Nitropdf and Wondershare PDFElement.

I'm looking for some insight into what might be happening, and what I could try to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With that many errors (as you have posted above), I suggest you do a Windows 10 Repair Install.

First, uninstall Sophos and Avast. Windows Defender is there for the time being.  If you have Drop Box installed, uninstall it for the time being.

**Repair Install Process:**

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

If the Repair will not run as per above, use the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key,
then run Setup on the USB Key.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Start with the option to Keep Everything.

When done, select Anti Virus.  Windows Defender is excellent. If you wish to replace it, just use one AV. More than one can compete with each other.

If you had Drop Box, re-install it at this point.

Try the above and then let us know.

Comment: I'll give that a try. For the record, I have all of Avast's automated defences disabled and only does anything when I manually tell it to scan something I want a second opinion on. As I understand it, that shouldn't cause issues, right? Sophos has never complained about being blocked from doing things, or identified Avast as a threat, anyway.

Comment: "I have all of Avast's automated defenses disabled "  It may be ok.  We always found it best for our clients to keep to one AV.  See what happens when you try the above.

Comment: Update: The dropbox uninstaller seems to have got stuck halfway. Should I just go ahead with the repair with it still (partially?) installed?

Comment: Yes you should go ahead with Repair Install and hopefully that will fix Drop Box as well.  Make sure documents have been backed up.

Comment: I followed your instructions, and everything seems to be back to normal. Thanks!

Comment: You are very welcome and I was pleased to assist you.